# Including a dataset in a R package

Tags: r, package, devtools

This question may seem pretty naive and I bag your patience.

I have saved `extension.RData` and documented it in `extension.R`. Both of them are saved in `/data` folder of the R package I am developing.

As I close RStuidio and reload the package, however, I cannot call the data until I execute one of the functions, `devtools::document()` or `devtool::load_all()`.  Does this suggest that my dataset is not in memory of the package? How could I not to execute `devtools` every time I start working on the package?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to install your package with `install` function from `devtools`.

Comment: Thank you, I run `devtools::install()` and load the library but it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As I have understood, you just created files `extension.RData`, `extension.R` (with documentation) in your project directory. However, this is not enough for RStudio to be able to reach your data. You have to install the package by running `devtools::install()` or clicking 'Build & Reload' button on 'Build' tab of RStudio.

**Edit**: Putting `extension.R` into `R` folder solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I did this too, but it still does not help...I am not sure what I have missed...

Comment: Can you call data by `{your_package}::extension` where `{your_package}` is the name of your package?

Comment: Thank you, echasnovski, it returns me `Error: 'extension' is not an exported object from 'namespace:my_package'`

Comment: Try to put `extension.R` into `R` folder. Normally, this is a good practise.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. How come http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html says a different thing?

Comment: It says "For example, the roxygen2 block used to document the diamonds data in ggplot2 is saved as R/data.R and looks something like this:".

Comment: Thanks, so I misunderstood...it makes the perfect sense to have `.R` in the `/R` folder.